# How to automatically save changes before running a Python script in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm writing Python scripts in Visual Studio Code, and I execute them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, a shortcut added by the extension [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). Is there a way to force VS Code to save the `.py` before running, thus eliminating the extra step to save the file?

Comment: So basically you want to create file with random name in some default folrder (or /tmp)? It is looks like you need to make custom plugin for this kind of task and bind some hot-key/shortcut to make this quick save. I think that this feature is not worth it (:

Comment: It sounds like it would be easy to make a macro to do this.  What command is your shortcut bound to?

Comment: @Mark I first thought this was a standard VS Code shortcut, but it's actually added by the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The shortcut is added by the Code Runner extension, which has an option to save the current file before execution.

```
{
   "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": false
}
```

More options are available in the [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)
[image: VS Code, Run Code]

Comment: where would i type the above snippet?

Comment: This one worked for me. @Nick or someone who is wondering where to put it, Command key + , and then click the three dots just under your 'search settings' bar and choose 'open settings.json'

Comment: In windows, click F1 -> Enter "Open Settings(JSON)". This will open the settings.json file. Now you can add the setting: "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true

Answer (score 15):

Simplest solution would be, File -> Auto Save. This is available in v1.29.x

[image]

Comment: This saves continuously, not just when I wish to run my code.

Answer (score 4):

On VS-CODE **Version 1.47** , go to : 
**File -> Preferences -> Settings -> (Search setting with "save"), go to bottom & follow like provided screenshots.**
[image: VS-CODE : save before run]

Answer (score 2):

File > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > Run Code configuration > Save file before run.

(Visual Studio Code 1.32.3, extension Code Runner 0.9.8.)

Comment: search saveFileBeforeRun in settings and check it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the extension [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) as I suggested in my comment.  It appears to be more powerful than the `multi-command` extension.  `macros` will take command arguments and also work with your snippets for instance.  It is not clear to me from the scant documentation that `multi-command` will do these things.

In your case:

```
 "macros": {
        "chooseNameHere": [
            "workbench.action.files.save",
            "your run python script here command"        
        ]
 }
```

I don't know what command your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>, it isn't one of the defaults so must be added by a python extension.  You can find it by searching in your keybindings and use that command.  And then any keybinding you like to this macro:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+.",
    "command": "macros.yourMacroNameHere"
  },
```

Comment: This could work, but after learning that the shortcut is added by Code Runner extension, I found a configuration for saving the file before execution.

Answer (score -1):

This is currently not possible, but the corresponding feature request is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21342).

#### Update

You can use [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command). To do so install the extension and add the following to your `settings.json`:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
        "command": "multiCommand.SaveAllAndDebug",
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.files.saveAll",
            "workbench.action.debug.start"
        ]
    }
]
```

And then add your custom command to the `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "Ctrl+Alt+N",
    "command": "multiCommand.SaveAllAndDebug",
    "when": "!inDebugMode"
}
```

Comment: I learned [this is possible with a simple configuration for the Code Runner extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48958318/705984)